# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I am attempting to minus a user inputted integer from product_qty within my sqlite3 database and I am getting this error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

These are the two functions that are involved when giving this error.

```
def Move():
        curItem = tree.focus()
        print (tree.item(curItem))
        contents = (tree.item(curItem))
        getvalue = contents.get('values')
        print(getvalue)
        selecteditem = contents['values']
        updateStock(id, getvalue[0])
        Database()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `basket` VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", getvalue)
        conn.commit()
        PRODUCT_ID.set("")
        PRODUCT_NAME.set("")
        PRODUCT_PRICE.set("")
        PRODUCT_QTY.set("")
        conn.close()

def updateStock(qty, id):
        t = (id,)
        Database()
        cursor.execute("SELECT product_qty FROM product WHERE product_id = ?", t)
        old_qty = cursor.fetchone()
        new_qty = 0
        new_qty = int(old_qty[0]) - qty
        cursor.execute("UPDATE product SET product_qty = ? WHERE product_id = ?", (new_qty, id))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
```

Comment: The order of arguments when calling `updateStock()`  is not the same as its definition.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the builtin `id` function to `updateStock`.  That does not end well.  I'd avoid that name for variables.  You need to find a way to determine the ID you're interested in, in your `Move` function.

Comment: while this helps in the sense that i now know i have to change the names of my variables, how would i determine the ID?

Comment: In `updateStock(id, getvalue[0])`, replace `id` with whatever you want `qty` to be in the function call.  (It also looks like you have your arguments backwards there)

Comment: @R.Place  There's not enough information to say, from your post.  Presumably it has something to do with `contents`.

Comment: would you recommend replacing `id` with `new_qty`?

Comment: No, it looks like you need the ID for your database query.

Comment: Okay, I will take a look at it and see if i can solve it